# Why does it do different move between posting only strings, and uploading image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have App, in which, there is a comment input field with image upload.
I designed it to be with ajax. So basically it reloads only partial after posting a comment.

The problem that I'm facing is, it automatically reloads when I try to post a comment with image uploading.

Is this how it's supposed to be? or my coding problem?

Can anyone tell me why and how I should fix this

**view**

```
<%=form_for(([@user, @comment]), :remote => true, :class => 'form' ) do |f| %>

        <%= f.text_field :body %>  
        <button type="submit" class="btn">POST</button>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can not send/upload a image via ajax!**

You need send a image via html, remove the `:remote => true`

```
<%=form_for(([@user, @comment]), :class => 'form' ) do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :body %>  
 <%= f.file_field :image %>
 <button type="submit" class="btn">POST</button>
<% end %>
```

Regards!

Comment: It doesn't matter to me as long as it send a image via html automatically now. and when posting a comment, it sends via ajax's remote.  So I wanted to make sure if it's possible to send image via ajax. It's not possible. right?

Comment: Take a look to my response! :D It's not possible.

Comment: Don't ask users to accept your response.  That's an improper use of comments.